# Understanding glmnet and cv.glmnet for multinomial model

Tags: r, regression

I'm fitting a binomial model in R using the `glmnet` package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnet). I have gone through several examples including the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.pdf) but I still have a question regarding the use of `glmnet` and `cv.glmnet`.

Here's a minimal example from the package vignette using built-in data:

```
# install.packages("glmnet")
library(glmnet)

data(BinomialExample)

# fit binomial glm
fit = glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")

# 10 fold cross validation
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")

# extract optimal lambda value
l.min = cvfit$lambda.min

# extract model for optimal lambda from *fit*
coef(fit, s = l.min)

# extract model for optimal lambda from *cvfit*
coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")

# check if both are equal
all.equal(coef(fit, s = l.min), coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, the example shows that the coefficients that we extract from `fit` and `cvfit` using `lambda.min` are exactly equal. The `lambda.min` value only occurs in the `cvfit`. Do we need to run

```
fit = glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")
```

at all? Since we can get the same results (coefficients) using only `cv.glmnet`.

Comment: Where does it say you need to run `glmnet` after `cv.glmnet`?

Comment: Maybe my question should be: do we need to run `glmnet` at all? It's not said anywhere explicitly but it's done in the vignette and that's why I was wondering if and why that's necessary.